# Multiple maven repository with the same credentials

Tags: java, maven

I am using the Apache Maven 3.5.2 and I face the same problem. I try to pull dependencies from two nexus-releases-repository, using the same account(username + password)

My `.m2/setting.xml` contains:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <username>username</username>
    <password>password</password>
  </server>   
</servers>
```

My project's `pom.xml` contains:

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <url>https://DOMAIN/repository/repoA-maven-public/</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <url>https://DOMAIN/repository/repoB-maven-public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

I am using the same account to login into both of repository, but I get maven error
`repositories.repository.id must be unique`. How that can be resolved

Comment: This should be configured on the side of the repository manager and not in configuration of Maven. Apart why do you have two different release repositories? Does usually not make sense...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Repositories section of pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) documentation:

> id, name: The id is used to uniquely identify this repository amongst many, and the name is a human readable form.

So, the id should be unique.

In our case, in settings.xml we have multiple **servers** definitions with the same credentials but different id values.